# php curl $_FILES to different server

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to do a curl post request with a `$_FILES` image data that was received.

The image is in `$_FILES["source"]`

I'm redirecting the image that was received to another server which manages the upload process.

```
function makeTheRequest($path, $data)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode != 200) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode( $result);
    }
}
```

The request is passing to the second server but without the file. I also double checked the `$_FILES` in the first server and it's ok but on the second server, it's empty

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: I just noticed that it is passing to the other server but the file isn't passing ..I'm also sure the is ok on the first server.

The $_FILES on the second server is empty